# To check if group of records contain a boolean in SQL

Tags: sql-server, group-by

So I have this table and  in SQL as below

Table : Fruits

Id = int,
Name = varchar,
Type = varchar,
isPrimary = bit

| Id | Name | Type | isPrimary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | Type A | 1 |
| 2 | Apple | Type B | 0 |
| 3 | Mango | Type A | 0 |
| 4 | Mango | Type B | 0 |
| 5 | Mango | Type C | 1 |
| 6 | Mango | Type D | 0 |
| 7 | Orange | Type A | 0 |
| 8 | Orange | Type B | 0 |
| 9 | Orange | Type C | 0 |
| 10 | Orange | Type D | 0 |

I need to get records where a group does not contain isPrimary =1. So in the above case, Orange is the record that I will get.

This is my query, but this is not working as expected.

```
Select Name from fruits
Group by Name
having isPrimary != 1
```

How do I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery. First, we get the name where isprimary=1 in the "inner query," then we excise the name from the outer query.    or you can use the left join with the same table to get the same result.

```
-- using left join
select distinct a.name from #u a
left join
(
select * from #u where Isprimary=1
)b on a.name=b.name 
where b.name is null

-- using subquery
 select distinct name from #u  where name not in (select name from #u where Isprimary=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using `having` clause with `max()` or `sum()`:

```
Select Name 
from fruits
Group by Name
having sum(cast(isPrimary as int)) = 0
```

Or

```
Select Name 
from fruits
Group by Name
having max(cast(isPrimary as int)) = 0
```

The `HAVING` clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword cannot be used with aggregate functions.

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/y-6heM3c)

Comment: Sorry, missed out on the datatype of the columns. isPrimary is a bit datatype column. Please check the latest edit to the question.

Comment: @TheFallenOne you just need to cast it to an `int` then

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different syntax using `MAX` and `NULLIF`

```sql
Select
  f.Name
from fruits f
Group by
  f.Name
having max(nullif(f.isPrimary, 0)) is null;
```

What this does is nulls out all the `0` values. If there are any remaining `1` values then we exclude it.

One final option: a `COUNT` with `NULLIF`

```sql
having count(nullif(f.isPrimary, 0)) = 0;
```

or using `CASE`

```sql
having count(case when f.isPrimary = 1 then 1 end) = 0;
```